# Access child's __dict__ from parent in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class where I want to be able to inspect its members and list them. However, I am only ever going to subclass this (in C++ this would be an abstract class), so I want this method to also return the members in its child class.

Is this possible or even a good idea in Python? And a follow up, is this possible without the `inspect` module?

Like so:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def GetMembers():
        return dict(vars(A))

class B(A):
    FOO = 'foobar'
    BAR = 'barfoo'
```

However, testing reveals:

```
>>> A.GetMembers()
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'GetMembers': <staticmethod object at 0x02219BB0>}
>>> B.GetMembers()
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'GetMembers': <staticmethod object at 0x02219BB0>}
>>> dict(vars(B))
{'__module__': '__main__', 'FOO': 'foobar', 'BAR': 'barfoo', '__doc__': None}
```

I want `B.GetMembers()` to include `FOO` and `BAR` like `dict(vars(B))` does.

Comment: Use [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) instead of `@staticmethod` and inspect the `cls` parameter. Your constraint "without the `inspect` module" makes no sense - that's the module whose point it is to inspect objects "by reflection", why do you want to not use it? And last but not least, in your code sample `FOO` and `BAR` are members of the class object `B` - they are **not** members of instances of `B`. There is no general way to enumerate the attributes of instances of a class without inspeting the instances themselves.

Comment: There are ways around the last thing by using certain patterns, like using [slots](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), or [traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) - or any other way where you explicitly add some sort of metadata to your classes. Just not for any object in general.

Comment: @staticmethod is terrible ... I never see any reason to use it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@staticmethods have no awareness of class nor class scope ... so there was no way for a static method to know it was called on a child class.

@classmethods recieve their class type as a first argument (just like instancemethods get self as a first argument) ... you can then call whatever on its cls.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def GetMembers(cls):
        return dict(vars(cls))

class B(A):
    FOO = 'foobar'
    BAR = 'barfoo'
```

Testing

```
>>> A.GetMembers()
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'GetMembers': <classmethod object at
 0x0286D130>}
>>> B.GetMembers()
{'__module__': '__main__', 'FOO': 'foobar', 'BAR': 'barfoo', '__doc__': None}
>>>
```

alternatively you may also want to access the parent classes dicts.
from a class(or instance) method you can access the baseclasses through `cls.__bases__`

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def GetMembers(cls):
      d = dict()
      for basecls in cls.__bases__:
        if hasattr(basecls,"GetMembers"):
          d.update(basecls.GetMembers()) #call inherited GetMembers
        else:
          d.update(dict(vars(basecls))) #no GetMembers inherited from basecls so just get its vars
      d.update( dict(vars(cls)))
      return d

>>> class B(A):
...     FOO = 'foobar'
...     BAR = 'barfoo'
...
>>> class C(A):
...     FOOBAR = "whatever"
...
>>> class X(B,A):
...     FOO = 'foobar2'
...     COLOR = 'red'
...
>>> class X(B,C):
...     FOO = 'foobar2'
...     COLOR = 'red'
...
>>> X.GetMembers()
{'__module__': '__main__', 'BAR': 'barfoo', 'COLOR': 'red', 'FOOBAR': 'whatever'
, 'FOO': 'foobar2', '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: nice, care to explain whats going on for us learners?, upvote anyway

Comment: there I gave a little more explaining